# перенос html+js кода с помощью appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую. Имеется следующий код

```
function complain(link) {
    $.get(link, function(data) {
       $('.complaint', data).appendTo('#up_msg');
       $(".popup-complain").toggle();
    });
}
```

По вызову этой функции в div в id up_msg должен вставляться html код из класса complaint, полученный с другой страницы. Html код вставляется без проблем, но среди него есть кусок js в `<script></script>`. Он то как-раз пропадает. В гугле не нашел причину такого поведения. Кто подскажет в чем причина и как исправить?

Comment: То есть внутри `.complaint` есть тэг `<script>` с JS кодом и он не попадает в `#up_msg`?

Comment: вы все правильно поняли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery получает содержимое через функцию `html()`, которая в свою очередь через `innerHTML`, а она по описания получает именно HTML код:

> Оно позволяет получить HTML-содержимое элемента в виде строки.

То есть `<script>` он специально пропускает, так как это не HTML.
Если бы вы даже вставили `<script>`, то он бы не выполнялся сам, это нужно делать в ручную с помощь [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Comment: @Vadim.K можно пробовать искать тэги `<script>` в блоке и выполнять их через eval()

Comment: насколько я вас понял,если не через eval(), другого пути как сразу задать этот js на текущей странице нет?

Comment: @Vadim.K нет, если у вас даже получиться вставить `<script>` он сам не выполнится.